# When is it appropriate to tag multiple languages in my question?

Tags: discussion, tags

Will tagging several languages on my question lead to a quicker answer?  What are the potential consequences of doing so?

Comment: Tags should describe what the the topic of a question so it's only appropriate to tag multiple languages if that's what the question is about. I don't see how it would lead to a quicker answer if that's not the case. At best you'd get the superfluous tags edited out, at worst you'd get down votes from people expecting to see a question about X that isn't about X at all.

Comment: Anyone who's looking through random new questions in a specific tag is most likely looking for questions to answer _in that tag_. If your question is tagged with multiple languages, you'd better be sure your question is actually directly relevant to every language you've tagged it with, or you're just going to annoy the people who might have otherwise considered answering your question.

Comment: It may well lead to a quicker closure.

Comment: Since this is self-answered, I'm assuming this is an attempt to create like a little mini-FAQ? It might be better to integrate advice like this into the [section on tagging in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). We used to have a community-curated FAQ on tagging, but [it was left behind in the MSE/MSO split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions), so nobody can find it anymore. This is the type of information that should *definitely* go in there, though.

Answer (score 10):

Tags exist to make it easier for people to find questions related to a particular topic. In order to make it easier for users searching by tag, it is important to ensure that every question is only tagged based on the technologies and languages being asked about.

If you tag several unrelated languages in your question, it introduces several problems.  First of all, it makes it difficult for us to know how to help you.  An answer that would make perfect sense in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), for example, may be useless if you really need [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c).

Often, questions tagged with several unrelated languages have other problems, such as lack of demonstrated effort (a so-called "gimme teh codez" question).  Tagging multiple languages would result in more people seeing the question, which is what you want. However, rather than getting an answer quicker, you're more likely to see your question downvoted and closed quicker as a result of this.

To sum up, less is more.  Adding only those tags which are the subject of your question will make it more likely you will get the answer you need, and adding superfluous tags will make it less likely.

Comment: Tagging multiple languages is also a sign of an off-topic question. Rarely does one have "a practical programming problem" in multiple languages at once. Multiple language tags also justify an answer written in each language which is extremely noisy and really hard to clean up fairly.

Answer (score 4):

There are legitimate situations where an on-topic question can involve more than one language. For example, questions on how to call unmanaged C++ code from a managed C# assembly could be on-topic, as could be a question on developing dynamic JavaScript from a ColdFusion web form. @JoeC is right, however, that many cases of multiple language tagging are going to be off-topic or otherwise problematic. Do not write questions asking for someone to write code and then add a tag for each language you would accept! These questions typically go to -5 votes or even below in a matter of minutes and are closed almost as fast.

Comment: *"questions on how to call unmanaged C++ code from a managed C# assembly"* Eh, I don't think so. You don't want a C++ expert there, you want a C# expert, so you should tag as C#. Especially in cases where you cannot modify the C++ code and just want to call into it, I'd say a C++ tag is a bad idea. It's a lot like the questions we occasionally get, How do I translate this Python code into C++? You don't tag that Python, because a Python expert isn't going to be able to answer that question.